# Should there be a tag for the Rule of Two?

Tags: tags, discussion

Rule of Two seems to get <strike>too much</strike> a lot of attention in the form of questions on SF&F.SE and it got me wondering, should there be a tag for [rule-of-two]?

1. It would make it easier to find answers sooner, thus reducing rule of two related duplicates
2. If the rule of two never interested you in the first place (me), then you could be able to ignore that tag and viola, everyone's happy!

Comment: For context: [44 questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22rule+of+two%22+is%3Aq) mention the Rule of Two by name.

Comment: Everything needs a tag. The more tags the better. [tag:rule-of-two], [tag:rule], [tag:of], [tag:two] you never know when someone is going to forget if it's "guideline of two" or "rule of two" or "thing of two".

Comment: I am partial to Cinnamon Buns-of-Two myself. If you only bring one, there will be...trouble.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary since we already have a Sith tag.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of having an answer, I’ll say that we don’t need a [rule-of-two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rule-of-two) tag. The [sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sith) tag is a good related tag, and adding a more specific tag isn’t worth the 40-something edits it would take.

Comment: I'm mainly just throwing this out there to see whether people think we don't need the tag, or if people are just tired of tag questions.

Comment: +1 There is already a star-wars tag and I see no need for anything more specific.